# Android Loading cached images into RecyclerView rearranges grid

Tags: android, grid, android-recyclerview

I'm using Recycler View on my project. I'm generating pinterestlike multicolumn grid. Everything works fine. My application loads data from externalstorage (images too). When loading was in UI thread, scrolling performance was really poor. So I've decided to create AsyncTask to load images from path and this is warking grate while scrolling down. When I'm scrolling up again I have problem because recreating cells are messing with grid layout. It is rearranging and it can be poor for users. Caching images in memory (lot's of them) is not good Idea i think, są maybe it is an option to store information about ImageView sizes for every cell and keep it for reuse?

My RecyclerView Layout adapter looks like this:

```
public class MainGridAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ArticleViewHolder> {
private List<Article> articleList;
private Context context;

public MainGridAdapter(Context context, List<Article> articleList) {
    this.articleList = articleList;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public ArticleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.article_cell, null);
    ArticleViewHolder avc = new ArticleViewHolder(layoutView);
    return avc;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ArticleViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    Typeface StagMedium = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Stag-Medium.otf");
    holder.articleTitle.setText(articleList.get(position).getTitle());
    holder.articleTitle.setTypeface(StagMedium);
    //Wczytuję obrazek
    Log.v("DDD", articleList.get(position).getTitle());
    Log.v("DDD", String.valueOf(articleList.get(position).getId()));


    //TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, articleList.get(position).getCover_height());
    //holder.container.setLayoutParams(params);
    BitmapWorkerTask task = new BitmapWorkerTask(holder.articleImage);
    task.execute(articleList.get(position).getCover_local_path());
    /*
    File file = new File(articleList.get(position).getCover_local_path());
    if(file.exists()) {
        BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath(), bmOptions);
        holder.articleImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
    */

    //Jeżeli materiał to video to pokazuję ikonkę
    Log.v("DDD", "Type: " + articleList.get(position).getType());
    if(articleList.get(position).getType().equals("article")) {
        Log.v("DDD", "Article");
        holder.articleVideoIcon.setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent);
    } else {
        Log.v("DDD", "Video");
        holder.articleVideoIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
    }


    holder.container.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.v("DDD", "Klikłem sobie na pozycję: " + String.valueOf(position));
            Intent intent= new Intent(context,SingleArticle.class);
            Log.v("DDD", String.valueOf(articleList.get(position).getId()));
            intent.putExtra("articleId", articleList.get(position).getId());
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return articleList.size();
}

class BitmapWorkerTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;
    private String path  = "";

    public BitmapWorkerTask(ImageView imageView) {
        // Use a WeakReference to ensure the ImageView can be garbage collected
        imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
    }

    // Decode image in background.
    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        path = params[0];
        File file = new File(path);
        if (file.exists()) {
            BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath(),bmOptions);
            int width = bitmap.getWidth();
            int height = bitmap.getHeight();

            //Bitmap resized_bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, Math.round(width / 2), Math.round(height / 2), false);
            //return resized_bitmap;
            return bitmap;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Once complete, see if ImageView is still around and set bitmap.
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (imageViewReference != null && bitmap != null) {
            final ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
            if (imageView != null) {
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You can better use Image cache Library  like Picasso, Glide. I think the problem here is with Recyclerview, as it loads data every time you scroll. The code you have write now will load data every time. But if you use  Image cache Library, It will load  the cached image instead of loading it again from the path(local or remote). Caching image is the best case .. hope it helps.

Comment: I've thought about it but isn't it the same when I will use picasso async? Loading from cache also take some time, so while fast scroll it wont handle it instantly. In other hand using picasso in UI thread will decrease performance while scrolling. Or I'm wrong? I have to load images from localpath, because client want app to load offline (after initialisation online and downloading data).

Comment: Nope that is not the exact case when you use Picasso, Picasso will  instantly stop caching the image when recyclerview child item loses it visibility(when scrolled)..plus you can also specify Picasso about what image cache size should be.. So I think you should try that..which will avoid your async task as well.. When the image is loading you can able to use holder to display default image/drawable user..

Comment: @HourGlass ok I'll check it on few lowend device and tell you results. :)

Comment: Ok, picasso doesn't change anything. First of all while fast scrolling down, UI freez while picasso is loading images from cache. And while scrolling back up is the same situation. Cells while recreating doesn't have information about their size, so the grid is recreating (animated positioning elements). So this is not the issue with image loading. Issue is with storing information about imageview size to remember it while recreating cells.

Comment: http://codex2android.blogspot.in/2015/11/picasso-android-example.html

Comment: Thx but this url has nothing to problem with recycler view grid. The problem is that recycler view doesn't know cell size until image is loaded. Picasso doesn't cache whole cells or their dimensions but only images. It is working well but fast scrolling causes the same problem. Staggered grid view layout rearrenges after image loading is complete. Let's stop looking for solution for loading images because it's not the case. On iOS when I created this app I've cached sizes for cells and than there was no problem with recreating them properly. How to do that here

Comment: And I don't want to crop images while loading if this was your idea. They have to show like they are witch correct aspect ratio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I've solved my problem. The thing is that API, and datastructure are also my code, so I've started to store in SQLite thimbs sizes. In this way I can set cell size in "OnBindViewHolder" like this:

```
 TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,         articleList.get(position).getCover_height());
 holder.container.setLayoutParams(params);
```

You can also download Bitmap, and store height in List or array and do the same. Ofcourse height of the container should be converted to dp but it is working like a charm. The problem with floating items is solved. Thx for help :)